# Jquery - ZeroClipboard works only in second click

Tags: javascript, jquery, zeroclipboard

I'm trying to copy text to clipboard by using ZeroClipboard.
It works good, but only in the second click on the button and not in the first click.
I saw few solutions in Google but none of them fixed my problem.
Thanks!

```
$("body").on('click','.copyToClipboard', function (event) {
var clientTarget =  new ZeroClipboard( $("#copy_to_clipboard"), {

        moviePath: "js/ZeroClipboard.swf",
        debug: false
    } );

    $('#copy_to_clipboard').attr('data-clipboard-text', texttocopy);
    alert(texttocopy);
    clientTarget.on( "load", function(clientTarget)
    {
        $('#flash-loaded').fadeIn();

        clientTarget.on( "complete", function(clientTarget, args) {
            clientTarget.setText( args.text );
            $('#data-to-copy-text').fadeIn();


        } );
        alert(args);
    } );

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize the clipboard outside your click function like,

```
var clientTarget =  new ZeroClipboard($("#copy_to_clipboard").attr('data-clipboard-text',texttocopy ),{
    moviePath: "js/ZeroClipboard.swf",
    debug: false
}).on( "load", function(clientTarget){
    $('#flash-loaded').fadeIn();
    clientTarget.on( "complete", function(clientTarget, args) {
        clientTarget.setText( args.text );
        $('#data-to-copy-text').fadeIn();
    });
    alert(args);
});

// get the text only on click of .copyToClipboard
$("body").on('click','.copyToClipboard', function (event) {
    var texttocopy = $('#copy_to_clipboard').attr('data-clipboard-text');
    alert(texttocopy);
});
```

Comment: This solution doesn't works. Text is still not copied in first click. @Rohan Kumar

Comment: You need to add attribute on complete of zeroclipboard event, then you can get in on your click event.

Comment: Can you please edit you answer with this addition. I don't understand you exactly @Rohan Kumar. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you make an online demo for it.